# How to set password to access extension in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

How to set password to access extension in Microsoft Edge?

I tried other extensions in Microsoft Edge but I have not found any.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot set passwords to lock access to extensions. However, if your purpose is to block an extension or force an extension to be installed, you may be interested in some of the extensions **group policies** in Edge. Please check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensions).